# Xaml live edit doesn't work with custom solution configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In VisualStudio 2017, from any fresh solution, we have the two classic configurations: `Debug` and `Release`.

I added some others custom configuration and the Xaml Live Editor doesn't find any element to update in any page, but with the `Debug` configuration, it works well.

I can't find anything or any keyword to find my answer, so I am asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered here: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/371461/xaml-live-edit-edit-and-continue-doesnt-work-with.html)

> Evgeny [MSFT] · Nov 01 at 02:19 PM
>
> Thank you for your feedback! You need to set XamlDebuggingInformation msbuild property to true in your configuration ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.tasks.windows.markupcompilepass1.xamldebugginginformation ). By default it is

```
<XamlDebuggingInformation Condition="'$(XamlDebuggingInformation)' == '' and '$(ConfigurationName)' == 'Debug'">true</XamlDebuggingInformation>
```

> It is not recommended for Release configuration as it increases the
>   size of your assembly by embedding file name, line and column info for
>   each element in XAML files.

**Edit**

The above solution is for **WPF** !

For **UWP** put this into the `.csproj` (Under `Project` tag) of your project

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- XAML DEBUG INFOs -->
    <DisableXbfLineInfo Condition="'$(ConfigurationName)' != 'Release'">false</DisableXbfLineInfo>
</PropertyGroup>
```